# Bigquery too many nested views and etc

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, powerquery

I am doing queries in Google BigQuery through Power Query (excel).

I've already created many tables and I've been using and updating them without a problem. However, after doing a simple change in in my most refined tables (that have been working okay for some months) a error suddenly appeared;

"Too many nested views/persistent user-defined functions or possible circular reference of views/persistent user-defined functions referenced in query. Only 16 levels of nested views/persistent user-defined functions are allowed."

I've already checked the whole archive, and haven't found any circular reference.

Have someone ever experienced this problem? Do you have any clue about how to solve it?

Comment: Review Query Structure: Check your query for unnecessary nesting of views or functions. Simplify it to reduce nesting levels.

Eliminate Circular References: Ensure there are no circular references between views or functions.

Optimize Query Logic: Consider optimizing your query to achieve the same results with fewer nested views or functions.

Comment: Hi - if you don’t update your question to show the relevant table and view definitions then there’s not a lot anyone can do to help you